# What is the value of gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds?

Tags: c#, xna, mono, monodevelop, monogame

I was wondering what is exactly the value of `gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds` in a second?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the game is running at 60 frames per second the value is likely to be 1 / 60 = 0.0166 seconds.

Answer (score 10):

`gametime.ElapsedGameTime` returns the time elapsed ***since the last update***, not the total game time. For this, you need `gametime.TotalGameTime`.

It is returned as a `TimeSpan`, so the last part (`TotalSeconds`) is a property of that struct. Since it's a TimeSpan, you have full access to other properties, like `TotalMilliseconds` or methods like `Compare`.

And since TotalSeconds is a `double`, it will indeed be 0.5 if the elapsed time is 500 milliseconds.

Answer (score -4):

`gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds`, as the name suggests, is the total number of seconds your game has been running. So if your game has been running for 1 second then this will be equal to 1. If your game has been running for a minute then this will be equal to 60.

Is there more to your question?

Comment: so if my game has been running for 500 ms then this will be equal to 0.5?

Comment: @MesutDarvishian It's a TimeSpan afterall, if you need milliseconds why don't you use .TotalMilliseconds?

Comment: No i don't need Milliseconds i just want to know what is value of TotalSeconds between seconds? So, Am i right? if my game has been running for 500 ms then this will be equal to 0.5?

Comment: @MesutDarvishian Why don't you try it? It takes about 5 seconds to create a new Timespan of 500 ms and check the result.

Comment: -1. ElapsedGameTime has nothing to do with the time since the game has been running. It is the time since the last Update() call.